# nginx location regex angular routing

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-routing, nginx-location

I'm currently trying to get an angular 8.x based application with routing to work on my development server. I 've configured a server that provides an api on the root route as well as an angular application that should be running at a different route. The following should providea minimum nginx-config example:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443;

  root /home/user/;
  server_name sub.tld.com;

  ssl_certificate /path...;
  ssl_certificate_key /path...;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:10020/;
  }

  location ^~/dashboard {
    alias /home/user/my-dashboard;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    index index.html;
  }
}
```

Since location expressions that start with a regex are priorized upon execution I'd have expected to work with the normal `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` call that works for angular application situated in the `/` location.

Generally routing does work, however reloading the page leads to an error responding, that the /index.html file cannot be found.

Has anyone out there experience with such a deployment pipeline, and give any meaningful suggestions?

Comment: Yes, wait for a minute

Comment: let me know if my answer helps you.

Comment: Well, the problem is, that my api runs on the `/` location, and the dashboard application itself runs under the ^~dashboard route which most likely leads to the conventional try_files command not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the **location** in order to let the angular to decide the routes, also this **will fix the reload issue.**

```py
location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html;
      expires -1;
      add_header Pragma "no-cache";
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";


      # Old deafult, I comment this because i have SPA app look: line 55
      # try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ =404; 

      # If the route dont exist return index.html 
      # This is the best option for (SPA Applications) like: React, Angular 5, Vue.js and Angular.js
      try_files $uri /index.html; 
    }
```

You can take a look at my `nginx.conf` file, where I have a flask server for the api and the NGINX, serves the angular dist files.

Also, you can check my repository where I show a working example of how to use (NGINX, Angular 5, Docker, Flask)

> https://github.com/George35mk/Docker-NGINX-NG5-Flask-Elastic

### nginx.conf

```py
# ==============================================================================
# New Config
# ==============================================================================

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile    on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  gzip  on;

  # Configuration for the server
  server {

    listen 80;

    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://flask_api:5000;
    }

    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html;
      expires -1;
      add_header Pragma "no-cache";
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";


      # Old deafult, I comment this because i have SPA app look: line 55
      # try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ =404; 

      # If the route dont exist return index.html 
      # This is the best option for (SPA Applications) like: React, Angular 5, Vue.js and Angular.js
      try_files $uri /index.html; 
    }

  }

}
```